# JavaScript alerts that JSON.parse object is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just wrote an script to get results from PHP file in json format, but after parsing it using JSON.parse or even jQuery, the object is empty and undefined! Note that the PHP returns the json string and works correctly. Here is the sample result:

```
{"status":"success","data":{"link":"http://example.com/file.pdf","size":"1 MB"}}
or
{"status":"failure","data":{"error":"some error occured!"}}
```

Here is a sample of my code:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function (){
        jQuery('#form').submit(function(event){
            jQuery('#loading').show();
            var formData = {
                id : jQuery('#id').val()
            };
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'script.php',
                data : formData,
                datatype: 'json',
                cache: false
            })
            .done(function(response){
                jQuery('#loading').hide();
                var obj = JSON && JSON.parse(response) || jQuery.parseJSON(response);
                alert(obj.result); // here says undefined and also the below if/else doesn't work
                if(obj.status == 'success'){
                    jQuery('#result').html('<span style="color: green;">' + obj.data.link + '</span>');
                }
                else if(obj.status == 'failure'){
                    jQuery('#result').html('<span style="color: red;">' + obj.data.error + '</span>');
                }
            });
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
<div>
    <form action="script.php" method="POST" id="form">
        <p>
            <label for="id">ID:</label>
            <input type="text" name="id" id="id">
        </p>
        <p>
            <button type="submit">submit</button>
        </p>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="loading" style="display: none;"><img src="loading.gif" alt="loading..."></div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

And I'd previously attached jQuery v1.10.x to the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though you misspelled the `dataType` attribute, jQuery will make a guess at the response type and parse it for you. There's no reason to call `JSON.parse()` (or `jQuery.parseJSON`).

Comment: @nexita The `response` parameter to the `.done()` callback will be the parsed object.  You just use it directly.

Comment: I just changed the code and used the response itself as the obj. But now I have the json string in response and other things are still undefined, such as response.result

Comment: @nexita you can use your browser's developer console to examine what exactly is coming back from your server.

Comment: @nexita also according to the JSON you posted at the top of the question, the returned object doesn't have a "result" property.

Comment: Everything is okay, but my if/else doesn't work because of I have no json parsed and i'd failed trying to parse it. the issue still remains!

Comment: @nexita unfortunately I don't know what you mean. Have you changed your `.ajax()` call so that "dataType" is spelled properly? Have you checked the developer console to see what is actually being returned from the server? Have you added a `console.log()` to see what the value of the `response` parameter is?

Comment: i just fixed that before posting the question, i already have checked about status in my if/else, there is no result anymore. but the problem remains. you told me because of dataType i put in my AJAX call, the response should be a parsed json as an object. but it's not! I still have a plain text in this variable. There is no object!

Comment: @nexita have you checked the developer console to see what's being returned from the server yet? That will tell you what's going on.

Comment: here is what i got from console that shows response variable in done: {"status":"success","data":{"link":"dl2\/2015\/02\/w3\/test.pdf","size":"850.69 KB"}}

Comment: @nexita OK, well there is no "result" property in that object, is there?

Comment: i told you once, i had fixed the code and replaced result with status. there is no problem with that anymore. check the first post again. I also removed the JSON.parse and used response variable directly as you said. But as you see, the response variable does not contains the parsed json as an object, it contains the json as plain text.

Comment: This is a wildly entertaining read. Please, @nexita continue berating the person trying, for reasons unknown, to help you.

Comment: Can you please run and check the live version of my code yourself? http://papergate.ir/oldu/autodl.php ... just enter the "10.1016/j.carbpol.2014.06.033" ( without quotes) as value into the textbox and click on pink button.

Comment: @nexita Yes, that returns an object. I don't see any errors in the console or any logging. If that response is being received by your jQuery function, then it will be parsed. You can use `console.dir(response)` instead of `console.log()` to see that it is, or `console.log(typeof response)` to explicitly see the type.

Comment: I'm so sorry. I did use console.log(typeof response) and I got String as response of it! :D Even the console.dir(response) gave me a json string. How do you say it is an object?! on the web right now.

Comment: @nexita OK, and you've got "dataType" instead of "datatype"?  If you *do* explicitly add a `JSON.parse()`, do you get an object?

Comment: OMG, thanks. Unfortunately i didn't get your mean at first, the T should be capital on dataType :D I'm so sorry about disturbing you about that. Thank you and have a great day.